# Is there a default JavaScript file naming convention?

Tags: javascript, filenames

So I've just started building my personal website, and I need an HTML file, a CSS file, and JavaScript file. But, I'm not sure what to name my JavaScript file. Here are some of my thoughts:

- "index.js"
- "app.js"
- "main.js"

Please correct me if there *is* a default JavaScript file naming convention. Otherwise, I might go with "index.js" because it sounds the most natural.

Help would be appreciated!

Comment: You could call it `MyAmazingApp.js` nobody would care. Call it what you want.

Comment: As @phuzi said, you can call it whatever you want, one thing I would like to highlight.  Whatever pattern you choose, keep consistency, follow that rule for every single file you create.

Comment: True, but if I'm working with a team, it wouldn't sound consistent.

Comment: If you're working in an organisation then it's possible they have a coding standard that you could refer to.

Comment: My favorite filename is [eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee/e.js](https://github.com/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee/blob/eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee/e.js)

Comment: @GOTO0, Went to your link. It's interesting to find that Github UI breaks on very large repo names without any word-dividing characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is really up to you, although `index.js`, `app.js`, and `main.js` are usually what is used to name the main JavaScript file of an application. For other `module` or `component` files, use a name that describes what the code within the file does, like `user.js` for a file that handles everything related to your application users.

Answer (score 2):

https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html

This URL shows JavaScript's naming conventions.
But naming is up to you.
Naming conventions come in many forms, but I recommend that you use the prescribed method.
This will make it easier for other developers to understand what you've made, and it's easier for you to understand what other developers have made.

Best regards.